# Search in string and quote around occurrence

Tags: javascript, string

Working with Javascript I need to be able to search a string input from a user and replace occurrences of semicolons with commas. Issue I have ran into is I need to be able to search the string for any commas that already exist, and quote around to the last and next occurrence of the semicolon.

Example:
User input is `12345;Joran,Michael;02;17;63` it should be converted to `12345,"Joran,Michael",02,17,63`

My includes is able to locate the occurrence of a comma in the original string `var srch = source.includes(",");` and my replace is `var converted = source.replace(/;/g, ",");` which works fine, just need to figure out how to get to the last/next semicolon to place the quotes.

Using an if/else depending on if srch evaluates to True -- if true, add the quotes and then convert the rest of the string and return to the user; if false, convert and return.

I'm sure there's a way to do this with regex that just hasn't came to me yet so any suggestions on what to look at would be great.

Comment: Is your output format CSV? Is your input format similarly well-defined? (For example, can the data ever contain escaped semicolons, quotation marks, or newlines?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd do this in two steps. First match non-`;` characters which have at least one `,`, and surround them with quotes. Then replace all `;`s in the result with `,`:

```js
console.log(
  '12345;Joran,Michael;02;17;63'
    .replace(/[^;,]*,[^;]*/g, '"$&"')
    .replace(/;/g, ',')
);
```

Comment: $& is what I was forgetting to find the match! Thank you! It's been way too long since i've had to work with regex.

Answer (score 0):

Split the string by `;`

```
.split(';')
```

which gives you an array.

Convert the elements that include a `','` to `"${element}"`

```
.map(s => s.includes(',') ? `"${s}"` : s )
```

Convert the array back to string

```
.join(',')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    var str = '12345;Joran,Michael;02;17;63';
    var arr = str.split(";");
    var letters = /^[A-Za-z]/;
    var final_str = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        final_str = arr[i].match(letters)?final_str +'"'+ arr[i]+'"'+",":final_str + arr[i]+",";
    }
    console.log(final_str.substring(0,final_str.length -1));
```